# Cpplint could not find executable

Tags: visual-studio-code, cpplint

I am trying to activate cpplint within vs code. I have installed it in Anacanda environment where executable

```
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/cpplint
```

I have a link to it

```
ls -l /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/cpplint
```

Unfortunately per visual code cpplint extension still getting error of "Cpplint could not find executable"

Please, advice to configure it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

*Download and install*

`sudo apt-get install python-pip`
`pip install --user cpplint`

*Verify install result*

`ls -l /usr/local/bin/cpplint`

If you still have issues check **cpplint.cpplintPath** and verify the execution path is set correctly.

Also, if you installed cpplint into `~/.local/` directories, by default `~/.local/bin` is not included in PATH. So to fix just that add:

`export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin/`
to your `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Strangely, my vscode cpplint plugin cannot find even when it is in PATH. If I open a terminal inside vscode it finds "cpplint", but complains anyway. My solution was to add this to user settings `Ctrl+Shift+P` `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` and put this line: `"cpplint.cpplintPath": "/home/your_username/.local/bin/cpplint",`. Note that I'm using cpplint plugin `mine.cpplint` (I guess it's the "official").

Comment: @igormcoelho I *think* there may be a bug in this plugin where it searches for the executable on the local machine, not the remote when it shows that error.